# How to Get Application Current Path in MFC(VC++)?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How to Get Application Current Path in MFC(VC++) ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
TCHAR szDirectory[MAX_PATH] = "";
::GetCurrentDirectory(sizeof(szDirectory) - 1, szDirectory)
```